# Drag and Drop touch event

Tags: android, android-layout, events, drag

I hope someone can help.

I have two (and some background image views) layout views on one activity, one is a background the other is to the left and contains other controls to manipulate several `textview` parameters size etc.

I have `textview`s with `Drag` events, which is working well.
When I drag one of these ``textview underneath the other (control) button layout. They can still be touched and dragged through the control layout.

I've tried setting the `android:clickable="true"` and tried this and all combinations of this on the layouts and the drag event still goes through to the `textview`.

[image]